# Is there a way to syntax highlight constexpr variables in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, constexpr

When I create an enum, the members of it are in blue and italics in my code. I would like something similiar for a constexpr variable (C++ 14 or later). Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get exactly what you're looking for.

But, in this statement:

```c
constexpr double MY_VARIABLE;
```

...you can change the formatting of `constexpr`, `double`, or `MY_VARIABLE` independently, with side effects affecting other variables and keywords too. Here's how:

---

I just tested this in Eclipse Version 2023-03 (4.27.0), and it works:

Window --> Preferences --> C/C++ --> Editor --> Syntax Coloring.

In the "Element" box, expand "Code" --> choose **`Keywords`**. Change its color. That affects `conxtexpr` *and all other keywords,* such as:

- `if`
- `else`
- `typedef`
- `using`
- `auto`
- `return`
- `template`
- `class`
- etc.

To see the colors and formatting for enums, look for **`Enum Classes`**, **`Enumerators`**, and **`Enums`** in the same "Element" box, so you can borrow those settings if you like.

If your goal is to change the `double` part, for instance, in `constexpr double`, that is controlled by the **`Built-in types`** option in the "Element" box. But, again, that changes *all* built-in types, not just those preceded by `constexpr`.

If you'd like to change the `MY_VARIABLE` part of, for instance, `constexpr double MY_VARIABLE`, when it is a global variable, that is controlled by the **`Global variables`** element. You can make it `Italic` too:

[image]

I don't think there's a way to affect just `constexpr` but no other keywords, without a custom extension or custom syntax highlighting scheme or something.

Here's a screenshot. You can see in the "Preview" section other keywords affected and now white in my case too. I verified in my main editor that this changed `constexpr`.

[image]

### Switch to VSCode

My last bit of advice to you is that unless you need the amazing indexing capabilities of Eclipse, since Eclipse is the clear winner here for absolutely gigantic projects and code bases (ex: 1 GB ~ 100 GB repos such as those I've used at my previous two companies), switch to VSCode. As a long-time Eclipse user, I've switched to VSCode and find it overall much better. I still keep Eclipse installed, however, for when I need to track down some code and need Eclipse's far superior indexer.

### References

1. I used my document here, under my section "Now update your doxygen syntax highlighting colors", to remind myself how to do this: [Eclipse setup instructions on a new Linux (or other OS) computer](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LbuxOsDHfpMksGdpX5X-7l7o_TIIVFPkH2eD23cXUmA/edit?usp=sharing).
2. GitHub Copilot also says the same thing if you simply ask it, `Is there a way to syntax highlight constexpr variables in Eclipse CDT?`. Other AIs to check with include Bing Chat, ChatGPT, and Google Bard. But, remember, Stack Exchange warns you each time you add an answer:

   > Reminder: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools are not allowed on Stack Overflow. [Learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy).

   And, a lot of people [utterly despise AIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77523559/is-there-a-way-to-syntax-highlight-constexpr-variables-in-eclipse-cdt/77524182#comment136670433_77523559) and may ["fart in your general direction"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWBUl7oT9sA) if you try to use or talk about them.

   But, I use them *every single day* in professional programming, and will *never program again without them,* because they are so useful! They are *amazing.* They do not *replace* me; they *enhance* me.

Comment: Gabriel, my apologies for the sarcasm; I thought you were assuming I asked right away without serching myself. Thanks for the very complete answer. My desire ist to highlight MY_VARIABLE but only if it is constexpr, seems not so easy at the moment.... I agree with your point of view regarding AI, still I should use it more often. I did now on this question. Thanks again.

Comment: @Martin_from_K, thanks. Yeah, I was literally just trying to be helpful. You may not have enough reputation to see it (I don't know), but your question has 2 close votes. When it hits 3, it's over. Nobody can add an answer, and you're stuck wondering why nobody helped you. So, I was encouraging you to use what I use when nobody else helps me: AIs. I wanted to help you still get an answer in the event your question were closed, and this is the type of question AIs are frequently pretty good at answering, or for which they can at least point you in the right direction to figure it out.